# How to find supported architectures from docker compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For [a project](https://github.com/victronenergy/venus-docker-grafana) I am trying to run, I get `ERROR: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8...` when trying to install from a compose file.

I suspect arm32 is supported, but would like to check what architectures are supported before switching to 32 bit OS. Is this possible from a compose file?

Comment: A compose file doesn't specify an architecture. That's determined by the docker daemon where a Docker image is built. You can inspect an *image* to see what architecture  it supports.

Comment: @larsks I tried what you mentioned on images retrieved from the compose file on a different system that works. Only seems to show the current architecture and no others.